# Android ContactsContract.Contact missing constants from the API?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, contactscontract, android-2.1-eclair

I've been using the ContactsContract api for some time now and I've come across two "columns" listed in the API page for ContactsContract.Contacts that do not appear to actually be assessable.

The values are (under the columns heading):
"NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID" and "DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY"

By my reading of the API these two values would seem to connect to the Structured Name (in DATA) used to construct the display name for the given contact. Having access to this directly from the contact table would be incredibly useful to me at the moment, but as far as I can tell they are not actually in the working api (I've tested against both 2.1 and 2.2).

The associated constants do not exist in the Contacts object, and attempting to access the fields directly (by using the lower case string versions I've seen in code dumps online) turns up with an sql error -- invalid column, as you might expect.

Has anyone had any better luck with accessing these? Are these actually in the API?

Edit:
I did some more checking and here's some related values from RawContacts that are listed on the API but appear to not actually be in it: DISPLAY_NAME_ALTERNATIVE, DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, DISPLAY_NAME_SOURCE, PHONETIC_NAME, PHONETIC_NAME_STYLE, SORT_KEY_ALTERNATIVE, and SORT_KEY_PRIMARY.

All of these appear to be features not yet in the API that are mistakenly not filtered out when the javadoc was released. If other folks are unable to access these features as well it might be worth filing a bug report over.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting thing about these items you mention.
Where it says ["since API level"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#DISPLAY_NAME_ALTERNATIVE) no level is mentioned.
I think a bug report is in order.

Comment: It has been reported, but so far there's no response. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11619

Comment: I'm guessing these are considered part of the "internal" api.

Answer (score 0):

I too found the same thing . When i went through the native contacts application they have been using the DISPLAY_NAME_ALTERNATIVE .In the API they have listed these in an interface

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumnsWithJoins.html

I also pulled the native contacts and checked the raw_contacts table. There I was able to find the "display_name_alt" as a coulmn.

So i dont know how to go about things . I dont know if the name of the column would help

Comment: Its best not to try and access the tables/column names directly given how frequently the contacts back end seems to change. I've been burned before when I tried to reach past what the API was doing. I suppose we'll have to wait until this portion is finalized and make do with work-arounds in the mean time.

Comment: Since we're using content providers, we don't really have access to the backend database. Even if we could though, it would be a pretty bad idea to build an app on top of that, as only the API interface is guaranted not to change significantly. A patch update could alter the tables and your app would stip working without notice.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to use some of these fields (ver 2.2), but the ContactsContract.DataColumnsWithJoins.DISPLAY_NAME_ALTERNATIVE static string is not visible.
So I used directly its value for the query, "display_name_alt", and I had that field's data.

I used also a query asking for all fields (putting null in 'String[] projection' variable of managedQuery() function) and retrieved all fileds.
I inserted a mistake in sortOrder variable, to retrieve the error and the automatically created SQL.
So SQL was like this

```
near "mimetype": syntax error: , while compiling:
SELECT 
data_version, 
phonetic_name, 
phonetic_name_style, 
contact_id, 
lookup, 
data12, 
data11, 
data10, 
mimetype, 
data15, 
data14, 
data13, 
display_name_source, 
data_sync1, 
data_sync3, 
data_sync2, 
data_sync4, 
account_type, 
custom_ringtone, 
status_update_id, 
status_updates.status AS status, 
data1, 
data4, 
data5, 
data2, 
data3, 
data8, 
account_type  AS ext_account_Type, 
data9, 
group_sourceid, 
data6, 
account_name, 
data7, 
display_name, 
in_visible_group, 
display_name_alt, 
contacts_status_updates.status_res_package AS contact_status_res_package, 
is_primary, 
contacts_status_updates.status_ts AS contact_status_ts, 
raw_contact_id, 
times_contacted, 
contacts_status_updates.status AS contact_status, 
status_updates.status_res_package AS status_res_package, 
status_updates.status_icon AS status_icon, 
contacts_status_updates.status_icon AS contact_status_icon, 
presence.mode AS mode, 
version, 
last_time_contacted, 
res_package, _id, 
name_verified, 
status_updates.status_ts AS status_ts, 
dirty, 
is_super_primary, 
photo_id, 
send_to_voicemail, 
name_raw_contact_id, 
contacts_status_updates.status_label AS contact_status_label, 
status_updates.status_label AS status_label, 
sort_key_alt, 
starred, 
sort_key, 
agg_presence.mode AS contact_presence, 
sourceid 
FROM
 view_data_restricted data
 LEFT OUTER JOIN agg_presence ON (agg_presence.presence_contact_id=contact_id)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN status_updates contacts_status_updates ON (status_update_id=contacts_status_updates.status_update_data_id)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN presence ON (presence_data_id=data._id)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN status_updates ON (status_updates.status_update_data_id=data._id) 
WHERE (1) 
ORDER BY contact_id mimetype
```

So you can see all available fields.

That I don't know how, is to get a Cursor with an SQL string from a Uri, like rawQuery() ...

Comment: Raw queries don't work with content providers. (See comments on above post)